# How can I prevent a dropdown from closing when I`ve selected an item?

Tags: combobox, silverlight-5.0

I have custom control, derived from combobox.

I want it to not close itself when I select an item. If I set the `IsDropDownOpen` property to false in `protected override void OnDropDownClosed(EventArgs e)`, this method just starts to chain invoke itself.

If `IsDropDownOpen` is set in the `OnSelectionChanged` handler nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you could use a `ListView` rather than a `ComboBox` if you don't want the open/close system?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No way. ComboBox is ComboBox, when a item is selected automatically closes it. ListBox is a good option here.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22814332/1547004

Essentially, install an eventFilter on the ComboBox's listview to catch the MouseButtonPress event to prevent it from passing through and causing the listview to close.