# QComboBox with checkboxes

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qstandarditemmodel, qabstractitemview

I'm creating QComboBox with checkboxes. How I can prevent collapsing of view on mouse clicking? I want to be able to set up checkboxes, but each time I click on item - drop-down of QComboBox is collapsed.

Note: currently I'm debugging Qt sources and looking for workaround...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you need to install an event filter to the combo box view, i.e.:

```
combobox->view()->viewport()->installEventFilter(someobj);
```

than you need to filter all mouse release events that happen on the combo box view to prevent its closing when you click on it:

```
bool SomeObject::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
     if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
         int index = view()->currentIndex().row();

         if (itemData(index, Qt::CheckStateRole) == Qt::Checked) {
            setItemData(index, Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
         } else {
            setItemData(index, Qt::Checked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
         }

         [..]

         return true;
     } else {
         // Propagate to the parent class.
         return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
     }
}
```

Comment: Event filter must be installed AFTER setting of custom view (with `QComboBox::setView`).

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: I think this is obvious, because `QComboBox::view()` returns different views before and after setting the new view.

Comment: I tested it (Qt4). First - I created `new QListView`, then I install event filters, then - set it to `QComboBox`. So last installed filter was a filter from QComboBox, and it supressed event processing.