# QAbstractItemView Tab Focus While Editing Item

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTreeView` populated with items from a model. When a call to `edit()` is made on an index, a custom editor displays. The editor consists of two `QLineEdit` widgets.

[image]

I want the focus to switch between the two `QLineEdit` widgets when Tab is pressed. However, pressing Tab cycles through everything else on my program. All my `QPushButton` and `QTabWidget` objects are included in the Tab order even though they are completely different widgets than my editor.

I've tried setting the tab order using `setTabOrder()` to loop it between the two `QLineEdit` widgets, however this still doesn't isolate the editor widget from the surrounding widgets. Why is this happening?

NOTE: I'm not trying to disable tab ordering anywhere else, just isolate it to my editor for the time being.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: @eyllanesc I did. I said I tried setting a tab order (specifically one that loops around to the start) but that was ignored. The other thing I tried was to disable the focus of all other widgets that are being focused that I didn't want to, but the problem there obviously is that when not editing, I want to be able to tab focus those.

Comment: Check out the **documentation**. It may not necessarily help with this but it very often helps.

Comment: Yeah I did, that's where I read about how `setTabOrder` works and why I can't loop it back to the start. It's the first place I go, but sometimes it's tough when you don't know what to look for.

Comment: Do the line edits even get the tab key event, or is it filtered out before?

Comment: @peppe The get the event. They cycle along with around 10 other things around my program. But I would like the tab to only cycle in the editor widget, similar to a QMenu only tabs through it's items.

Comment: So, worst case scenario, you could just subclass QLineEdit, reimplement the `event` method, and cycle the focus to the other line edit?

Comment: So is that the answer? Just.... not use it? There's really no way to isolate a widget for tab focus like the base QMenu class does to it's items? Or dialogs? or whatever without subclassing it and listening for keys?

Comment: Subclass the lineedit to be able to set a prefered sibling. Reimplement the keyevent and consume it on tab press. Manually set focus to the sibling.

Comment: @SebastianLange Would you mind posting this as an answer? I  subclassed `QLineEdit` and reimplemented both `eventFilter` and `keyPressEvent` and pressing tab fires neither event. I even reimplemented the `eventFilter` function found in the subclassed `QStyledItemDelegate` that holds the custom editor widget and all Tab key press events are not called. Other keys do however. It's being filtered somewhere and it's really annoying.

Comment: You need to install an event filter on `QTreeView` (or `view->viewport()`) and filter out "tab" keyboard events when start editing delegate is called. Unfortunatly I have no installed Qt on my PC now, so I can't provide a code sample. You may check this for some code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813494/qcombobox-with-checkboxes

Comment: `QMenu` realization also use reimplemented `event` method for correcting tab order

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I just installed an event filter on `QTreeView` and it's not getting any key press events either. It's so weird, the delegate gets key press event but not tab. The line edits get key press events but not tab. And QTreeView gets none.

Comment: @mrg95 did you try to set an event filter on viewport?

Comment: Yep. I did `treeView->viewport()->installEventFilter(treeView);` and there was no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily implemented using [`QWidget::focusNextPrevChild`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusNextPrevChild) as follows:

```
class EditWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
  EditWidget(QWidget *pParent) : QWidget(pParent)
  {
    QHBoxLayout *pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    setLayout(pLayout);
    pLayout->addWidget(m_pEdit1 = new QLineEdit ());
    pLayout->addWidget(m_pEdit2 = new QLineEdit ());
  }

  bool focusNextPrevChild(bool next)
  {
    if (m_pEdit2->hasFocus())
      m_pEdit1->setFocus();
    else
      m_pEdit2->setFocus();
    return true; // prevent further actions (i.e. consume the (tab) event)
  }

protected:
  QLineEdit *m_pEdit1;
  QLineEdit *m_pEdit2;
};
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much! I'm surprised it took so long when the answer was so simple. This is exactly what I was looking for :D :D :D